# JavaScript - Create elements using web component class

Tags: javascript, class, instance, web-component

I have a web component that only works when some properties are set, when I create the component with `Document.createElement()` I can't pass properties then an error happens in my component.

Is it possible to create the component by creating an instance of the component class or something similar and be able to pass parameters to it's constructor?

```js
customElements.define('x-card', class extends HTMLDivElement {
//...
}, { extends: 'div' });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "only works when some properties are set"?

Comment: On Apple Safari extending **Built-In Elements** will never work, Apple has stated so since 2016. So only Autonomous Elements (extends HTMLElement) or mess with polyfills

Comment: *I have a web component that only works when some properties are set* That is exactly why you don't build components this way.

Comment: @connexo how should I create components? Can you please recommend repositories to look into.

Comment: Show us **all** your source code and errors they produce; you are now asking _"I have a vehicle that doesn't take me forward; what is wrong?"_

Comment: @user5507535 No, just stick to what standard JS has and experiment with it until you feel confident. A lot of very useful information is here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new instance using `new WCard`. This requires having access to the `class` though.

Please note that custom element names preferrably should not start with `x-`.

So change your code:

```js
export class WCard extends HTMLDivElement {
//...
}

customElements.define('w-card', WCard, { extends: 'div' });

window.WCard = WCard;
```

This allows you to call `new` on the class globally, or if your code imports the class.

```js
const wcard = new WCard(...args);
```

Comment: I just created a Web Component that [starts with **x-**](https://jsfiddle.net/dannye/fyqdxe84/) Can you provide documentation that states that is not allowed?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I was wrong on that one. It's only advised that they shouldn't, just like they shouldn't start with `polymer-`. See http://webcomponents.github.io/articles/how-should-i-name-my-element/ for more info. Sindre Sorhus has also implemented this in his https://github.com/sindresorhus/validate-element-name and issues a [warning if a custom element name starts with `x-`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/validate-element-name/blob/main/index.js#L52).